# R session Aborted when use intersect in raster/terra

Tags: r, r-raster

When I try to use `raster::intersect` to compute the intersection of space polygons, Rstudio tells R session Aborted.

The error is occur in this line:

```
library(raster)
overlap <- raster::intersect(current_poly, other_polys)
```

The data information:

[current_poly data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ht511.png)

[other_polys data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijr9E.png)

The data is only 5mb, the format of my data is the same as the data in the official document. I can use the official example demo in `raster::intersect` successfully.

The demo is from [here](https://github.com/earthlab/neon-veg.git)

Comment: Since this is a bug, a better place to report it is at https://github.com/rspatial/raster/issues. But irrespective of where you post this, it is not going to be possible to help you much, unless you share the data as well.